# Unable to install any new extensions via composer in yii2

Tags: yii2, composer-php, yii2-advanced-app, kartik-v

I am trying to install a new widget but I am getting error. I need help with getting a solution.

```
F:\xampp\htdocs\mdc>composer require --prefer-dist miloschuman/yii2-highcharts-widget "*"
    ./composer.json has been updated
    The "extra.asset-installer-paths" option is deprecated, use the "config.fxp-asset.installer-paths" option
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.


  Problem 1
    - mongosoft/yii2-soap-client dev-master requires ext-soap * -> the requested PHP extension soap is missing from your system.
    - mongosoft/yii2-soap-client dev-master requires ext-soap * -> the requested PHP extension soap is missing from your system.
    - mongosoft/yii2-soap-client dev-master requires ext-soap * -> the requested PHP extension soap is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for mongosoft/yii2-soap-client (locked at dev-master, required as *) -> satisfiable by mongosoft/yii2-soap-client[dev-master].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - F:\xampp\php\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

**Composer.json**

```
{
"name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
"description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
"keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
"homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
"type": "project",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
    "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
    "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
    "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
    "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.13",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0",
    "luoxiaojun1992/yii2-tinker": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-grid": "@dev",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2": "@dev",
    "kartik-v/yii2-mpdf": "*",
    "moonlandsoft/yii2-phpexcel": "*",
    "nirvana-msu/yii2-showloading": "1.0.*@dev",
    "kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base": "^2.0",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-spinner": "@dev",
    "edwinhaq/yii2-simple-loading": "*",
    "c006/yii2-submit-spinner": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-detail-view": "*",
    "fedemotta/yii2-cronjob": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datetimepicker": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-date-range": "dev-master",
    "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.2",
    "linslin/yii2-curl": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput": "@dev",
    "kartik-v/yii2-dialog": "*",
    "google/apiclient": "^2.0",
    "delight-im/str": "^2.4",
    "mongosoft/yii2-soap-client": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-export": "@dev"


},
"require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",

    "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
    "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1"
},

"config": {
    "process-timeout": 1800
},
"extra": {
    "asset-installer-paths": {
        "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
        "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": "php init --env=Development --overwrite=n"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "kartik\\spinner\\": "",
        "nirvana\\showloading\\": ""
    }
}
}
```

I have already looked into some solutions but none of them have worked. I am stuck at this from hours and I am getting nothing in result. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: it is just asking you to install the soap extension as it cannot find , either enable in you php.ini cli or If you are using linux with php 7.+ then use this command
`sudo apt-get install php7.2-soap`, for a few people just running `composer self-update` ddi the trick

Comment: What's your exact problem? Why not install the given PHP extension?

Comment: @NicoHaase whenever I tried to install a new widget it doesn't install and gives me error

Comment: ....and what have you tried to solve that problem? For example, according to the error message, the SOAP extension is missing

Comment: @NicoHaase I did try to install the soap extension method but it still gives me this error again and again

Comment: show your `composer.json` file that you have updated, and what is the exception it is throwing after updating the `composer.json`?

Comment: **How** did you ensure that the extension was installed and activated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Above all the main problem wasnt addressed which was labelled as **Problem 1** in the OP's added exception message. Sorry about that.

You should also change the version of the `yii2-soap-client` to `dev-master` from `*` as the error says

> Installation request for mongosoft/yii2-soap-client (locked at dev-master, required as *) -> satisfiable by
>   mongosoft/yii2-soap-client[dev-master].

so change the

```
"mongosoft/yii2-soap-client": "*"
```

to

```
"mongosoft/yii2-soap-client": "dev-master"
```

in your `composer.json` and make sure you have enabled the extension in you `php.ini`

---

You need to switch to asset-packagist and disable the fxp-asset

For disabling the fxp asset add the following under the `config`

```
"fxp-asset": {
    "enabled": false
}
```

then switch to packagist via

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
    }
]
```

See reference [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/17218)

So your `composer.json` should look like below

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
    "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.13",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0",
        "luoxiaojun1992/yii2-tinker": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-grid": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-mpdf": "*",
        "moonlandsoft/yii2-phpexcel": "*",
        "nirvana-msu/yii2-showloading": "1.0.*@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base": "^2.0",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-spinner": "@dev",
        "edwinhaq/yii2-simple-loading": "*",
        "c006/yii2-submit-spinner": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-detail-view": "*",
        "fedemotta/yii2-cronjob": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datetimepicker": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-date-range": "dev-master",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.2",
        "linslin/yii2-curl": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-dialog": "*",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.0",
        "delight-im/str": "^2.4",
        "mongosoft/yii2-soap-client": "dev-master",
        "kartik-v/yii2-export": "@dev"


    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",

        "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
        "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1"
    },

    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800,
        "fxp-asset": {
            "enabled": false
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": "php init --env=Development --overwrite=n"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "kartik\\spinner\\": "",
            "nirvana\\showloading\\": ""
        }
    },
    "repositories": [{
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
    }]
}
```